# Getting data from override function

Tags: android, kotlin

This might be a little weird but I can't figure out how to pass data after an API call. I'm very new to object oriented programming.

`fetchedTags` is null after the `fetchTags()` call. How do I get the data?

For example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var fetchedTags: List<Tags>? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fetchTags()
        println(fetchedTags[0].name)
        fetchBooks()
        makeMapOutOfTagsAndBooks()
    }



    fun fetchTags () {
        //some processing
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val jsonData = response?.body()?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                val tagList: List<Tags> = gson.fromJson(jsonData, object : TypeToken<List<Tags>>() {}.type)
                fetchedTags = tagList

    }
}
```

Comment: why have you commented ===`//etc...)` { inside `onCreate`

Comment: I just wanted to remove unnecessary codes that aren't directly related to the question.

Comment: Remove `//`. this is not unnecessary codes. and run it. the issue will be solved. you will get values in `fetchedTags `

Comment: println(fetchedTags[0].name)
 add this line in

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                    val jsonData = response?.body()?.string()
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                    val tagList: List<Tags> = gson.fromJson(jsonData, object : TypeToken<List<Tags>>() {}.type)
                    fetchedTags = tagList
 println(fetchedTags[0].name)
    }

Comment: @Hitesh Sarsava, Yes, it is not null only on the onResponse call. I wanted some way to bring the data out because I have a lot more processing to do.

Comment: then make interface for that task in implement in class and call its method in onResponse

Answer (score 1):

```
fetchBooks()
println(fetchedTags[0].name)
```

Your are calling `println(fetchedTags[0].name)` right after making your http call, since it's asynchronous your list is null at this point.

call it on your `onResponse` function

Comment: Yes, it is not null at onResponse. So basically, I have to do all my processing inside onResponse? I have to do another HTTP call (fetchBooks()) inside it.

Comment: Basically yes, you can call fetchBooks(fetchTags) inside your onResponse

Comment: I see. I just thought there was another way to do it. Thanks!